# {character} is a synonym of {symbols}, but {characters} isn't

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there a reason for this? I've occasionally used [characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) because it seemed more appropriate than [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols), e.g. I'm having a hard time regarding [using hobby MF font with LaTeX, adding accented characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34627/) as being about "symbols". One way or the other, we should use the tags consciously; seeing that [character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) is a synonym of [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols) already, [characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) should probably be a synonym as well because there's no relevant semantic difference between singular and plural.

Edit:
Having learned more about how our tagging system works, [character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) should proabably be gotten rid of, *if* [characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) is made a synonym of [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols).

---

Edit2:

Alright, now both tags have tag wikis that emphasize the difference between them, and we're kind of using them accordingly:

> {symbols} is about specific non-alphabetic symbols or math symbols, e.g., about looking-up, constructing, or using symbols. For questions about {fonts} or alphabetic {characters} use the respective tag instead.

> {characters} is about the regular alphabetic characters that are part of some script in a language. For accented characters, add {accents}. For non-alphabetic characters, use {symbols} instead.

As long as we're not doing any merging (and I'm actually not sure that would be the best idea), I'd say **let's fix the weird synonyms for starters!**

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, *character* and *symbol* have different meanings.

- *Character* stands for an abstract symbol, for the meaning of it, independent of the graphical representation.
- *Symbol* means a glyph, the graphical representation.

In TeX and LaTeX, we have input and output, let's have a look.

- Input means characters. For example we have questions regarding encoding. I guess not specifically about characters, since typing on keyboard is not a TeX topic and also how to get non-keyboard characters is more concerning the operating system.
- Output means characters and symbols. There are more questions are about symbols than characters. For example, people rarely speak about a bullet character which could be represented by a filled circle or an empty one, or smaller like a dot. We speak about what should appear there.

Theoretically, we can cleanly separate characters if the actual glyph doesn't matter. But does it help the user, who comes here because of a character or symbol problem, does he differentiate? Does he know that he must type "character" for looking how to work with a backslash or a tilde (independent of the font), but not type "symbol"?

I think in practice it's ok to keep one tag for both. In consequence, we should make *characters* a synonym as well. I'll let that open for now, perhaps somebody would check and tell us, how many questions are really purely about characters.

Answer (score 2):

Based on observation, I don't think that the typical user of tex.sx is likely to differentiate correctly between [characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) and [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols). The problem is the same as in my former suggestion [Split the {bibtex} tag into {bibtex-format} and {bibtex-program}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/split-the-bibtex-tag-into-bibtex-format-and-bibtex-program) -- the distinction is (somewhat) meaningful in theory, but confusing in practice. I'd say it's about time to make [characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) a synonym of [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols).

Comment: I'm torn. I highly respect your expertise on tagging, but I'm really having a hard time putting the same label on symbol questions and character questions. Then again, we'd probably have to go through the 392 [tag:symbols] questions and check if they're tagged correctly, if we distinguish characters and symbols ...

Comment: @doncherry Simply ask yourself: Is there a distinction between {characters} and {symbols} that is easier to grasp for "typical" users than the distinction between {bib-format} (about the `.bib` file format) and {bibtex-program} (about being versed in `bibtex`s postfix stack language). If you can't come up with such an easy-to-grasp distinction, then it's time to merge.

Comment: how about "character-symbol" and "character-internal"? ("character-code" means something else entirely.)  i do see a useful distinction between the terms "symbol" ans "character" but agree that a novice might not.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Perhaps add your own answer to the present question and suggest definitions for the two tags.

Answer (score 0):

the names "symbol" and "character" mean quite different things to me, although i agree that they might not to a novice.  how about these "enhanced" names to distinguish:

- character-symbol
- character-internal

"character-code" means something else entirely, so isn't appropriate.